# Google Maps v2 Android custom tiles wms

Tags: android, google-maps, caching, wms

I'm using Google Maps v2 to display tiles from a wms. The tiles is displayed correct, everything all well so far. Now I need a cache functionality. I'am using the code provided here: http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/

Google Maps is caching tiles by default but it's not caching everything, tiles are not loaded at very high and low zoom levels (re-downloaded) and only tiles in the "middle" are loaded from cache. The main problem is when I close the app and reopen it Google Maps is not loading tiles from cache but re-downloads everything. Not sure why, cache is not cleared.

If anyone has any ideas for "fixing" the tile cache in Google Maps that would be great. if not, how can I get the downloaded tile from the example in the link?

Comment: I'm also referring same site. But getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) is not getting called do you know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to write your own downloading and caching algorithm and implement `TileProvider` instead of extending convinient `UrlTileProvider` like in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created my own downloader and caching. After some testing I realize that I need to use async downloading of tile images. I have tried to do this without luck. How can I return the tile image downloaded from async in getTile? (did that make any sense) any suggestion?

Comment: You don't need to create your own threds / async tasks. [TileProvider](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) "Calls to methods in this interface might be made from multiple threads so implementations of this interface must be threadsafe."

Comment: Ok, thanks. I use a simple HttpURLConnection to download the images and return byte array in getTile. When using getTileUrl the tiles downloads and displays way faster (no cache) than using getTile and my own downloader. The difference can be up to 10+ seconds. Any idea on this one too?

Comment: Not without seeing the code. I'd suggest to create a new question and someone will answer.